# Windows 2012 R2 Hyper-V VM stuck undoing changes at boot

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, windows-update, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows 2012 R2 Hyper-V VM currently stuck on

```
We couldn't complete the updates
      Undoing changes
Don't turn off your computer
```

I read online that this is an issue related to a Windows 8.1 update interacting with Gen2 Hyper-V guests, and the solution was to shut down the VM and disable secure boot until after you power it back up and the updates successfully complete. However, when I turn the VM back on I'm instantly back at this screen. Is there a way to clear this boot state or otherwise help this process along? I unfortunately don't have a useful checkpoint for this VM. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, yes, upon disabling the secure boot option and starting the VM, you are once again presented with the undoing changes screen. Be patient, let it do what it is doing. It may take a while, I read, for some folks over an hour. Last time I came across this, it took about 1/2 hour for the server to finally boot into Windows..